# DISM split image wrong size

Tags: wim, imagex

I'm trying to split a 19GB image to fit a FAT32 drive (can't format it now), and I'm using this command:

> Dism /Split-Image /ImageFile:D:\img.wim /SWMFile:D:\sp\split.swm /FileSize:myFileSize

My issue is that, no matter the value of `myFileSize`, the tool always creates a 5.5GB file.

So, with `myFileSize` set to 600 (for example), I end up with 24 600MB files and 5.5GB one (which can't be copied to my FAT32 drive).

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue as well. After searching the Microsoft's documentation (for the powershell split-image) I found the following excerpt [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dism/split-windowsimage?view=win10-ps):

> If a single file is larger than the value specified in the *FileSize* parameter, one of the split .swm files that results will be larger than the value specified in the *FileSize* parameter, in order to accommodate the large file.

I'm assuming that this applies to DISM also.

Comment: That's exactly what's happening; if your mounted WIM has a single file that is 5.5 GB in size, then at least one of those split SWM images are going to be 5.5 GB in size as well. OP may have to add that one file into an archive and split that archive to achieve what they want.

Answer (score -2):

Try use...

Dism /Split-Image /ImageFile:"D:\img.wim" /SWMFile:"D:\sp\split.swm" /FileSize:650

Comment: The author indicates this command does do what they expect.